# Angular 6 and spinners

Tags: angular, loading

I can't seen to get any spinners working in my angular 6 (now 7 i think) project. (using vs2017)

I am currently trying this one = https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng4-loading-spinner

And while it all seemed to npm install ok (other than getting angualr 6.0.0 dependency warnings) ... nothing happens.

in my module

```
import { Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule } from 'ng4-loading-spinner';
imports: [[ Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule.forRoot() ],...]
```

In my component

```
import { Ng4LoadingSpinnerService } from 'ng4-loading-spinner';
...
constructor(private spinnerService: Ng4LoadingSpinnerService...)
```

and in the method...

```
getDetails(){this.spinnerService.show();...}
```

And in the html...

```
<ng4-loading-spinner> </ng4-loading-spinner>
```

in the package.json...

```
"dependencies": {"ng4-loading-spinner": "^1.2.3",...}
```

I have tried the spinner tag in both the component html using it and in the base 'grand parent' component...

nothing ever shows up... no errors, no flash, nothing...

Comment: In which module exactly you are importing `Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule` to ?

Comment: perhaps the double array from the import in your NgModule is the issue, try:  `imports: [ Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule.forRoot() ]`. But perhaps that's just a typo while making this question

Comment: Add loading text and check if you could see anything  `<ng4-loading-spinner  [loadingText]="'Please wait...'"> </ng4-loading-spinner>`

Comment: I only have 1 module = the Entity.module.ts   All other components source that.  Thus the  Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule is there...

Comment: I removed the extra [] from the module import statement = still no spinner shows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be you're importing it incorrectly and have an extra `[]`.

Try `imports: [Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule.forRoot(), ...]` instead of `imports: [[ Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule.forRoot() ],...]`

Comment: I removed the extra [] from the module import statement = still no spinner shows...

Comment: Do you have the html component in your root element? Maybe it's being blocked by something on top of it. In addition, is your browser console outputting any errors? Are you importing it correctly in your `app.module.ts`?

Comment: After trying everything everyone suggested here, it didn't work.  So I went home, rested on it, came back in, tidied up the code a little, and did an ng build.  Now it works.  :P  SO something was out of place or in wrong spot.  I am not sure which or what, but in general this answer and the other suggestions for where i place the tags were likely correct.

Comment: Ah, just figured it out... stoopid me.    I had the tag and the call for the search component on a click event, which navigated away to other component, and thus hiding the component that has the spinner tag, and thus never showing the spinner.... my bad :P

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that the problem is due to where you are placing your html. Have you put the `ng4-loading-spinner` element within your app.component.html file?

Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbcm2e) working demo SlackBlitz and see if it's of any help.

Comment: I tried moving it to the app.component level and that also did not work.

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue on SlackBlitz at all?